# Leave-one-out cross validation: Relatively unbiased estimate of generalization performance?

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection, bias

I have read that leave-one-out cross-validation provides a relatively *“unbiased estimate of the true generalization performance”* (e.g. [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://jmlr.org/papers/volume11/cawley10a/cawley10a.pdf&ei=-LTeUdnSHLXF4AOCj4HIAw&usg=AFQjCNFZqgYqt128zLV2VRnKNHwa-amLhw&sig2=Sz8pp6GNBIJhTJCZqn0b4Q&bvm=bv.48705608,d.dmg)) and that this is an advantageous property of the leave-one-out CV.

However, I don't see how this follows from the properties of leave-one-out CV. Why is the **bias** of this estimator low when compared to others?

#### Update:

I keep investigating the topic, and I believe it has to do with the fact that this estimator is less pessimistic than, say, K-fold validation, since it uses all the data but one instance, but it would be great to read a mathematical derivation of this.

Comment: Hi Amelio - I have seen several mathematical derivations of this in the papers cited in this answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280665/does-k-fold-cv-with-k-n-loo-provide-the-most-or-least-variable-estimates/358278#358278 - is there one in particular you want to see ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a need for a mathematical derivation of the fact that in ML, with increasing training test size, the prediction error rates decrease. LOO -- compared to k-fold validation -- maximizes the training set size, as you have observed.

However, LOO can be sensitive to "twinning" -- when you have highly correlated samples, with LOO you have the guarantee that for each sample used as a test set, the remaining "twins" will be in the training set. This can be diagnosed by a rapid decrease in accuracy when LOO is replaced by, say, 10-fold crossvalidation (or a stratified validation, if for example the samples are paired). In my experience, this can lead to a disaster if generally your data set is small.

In a perfect world, you have also a validation set that you never use to train your model, not even in a CV setting. You keep it for the sole purpose of testing the final performance of a model before you send of the paper :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this topic but I think I can give you a concrete and elementary example of how least square cross-validation with the leave-one-out method produces an "unbiased" estimate of **integrated mean square error** ($\mathrm{IMSE}$ for short) in the context of **kernel density estimation**.

Recall a typical univariate kernel density estimator $\widehat{f}$:
$$
\widehat{f}(x)=\frac{1}{n h} \sum_{i=1}^n K\left(\frac{X_i-x}{h}\right),
$$
where we have imposed the following assumptions:

- A.1 $X_1, \cdots, X_n \stackrel{i . i . d .}{\sim} f$.
- A.2 $f^{\prime\prime}(x)$ is continuous and bounded in the neighborhood of $x$.
- A.3 The kernel function $K(\cdot)$ is a symmetric pdf which maximized at $0$ and satisfies:
  $$
  (i)\begin{aligned}\int K(u) d u=1\end{aligned},\quad
  (ii)\begin{aligned}\nu_2:=\int K^2(u) d u<\infty\end{aligned},\quad
  (iii)\begin{aligned}\kappa_2:=\int u^2 K(u) d u \in(0, \infty)\end{aligned}
  $$
- A.4 $h \rightarrow 0$, $n h \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, which means $n^{-1}=o\left((n h)^{-1}\right)$.

Under the above assumptions, the integrated mean square error can be computed as:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{IMSE}\left(\widehat{f}\right) =& \int \operatorname{MSE} \widehat{f}(x) d x\\ 
=& \frac{1}{n h}\int K(u)^2 d u+\frac{h^4}{4}\left(\int u^2 K(u) d u\right)^2 \int\left[f^{\prime\prime}(x)\right]^2 d x+o\left(h^4+\frac{1}{n h}\right),
\end{aligned}
$$
which can be easily derived from the bias rendered by KDE (the derivation can be referred to in this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/439199/expected-value-and-variance-of-kde/588761#588761)).

Accompanied with this knowledge, let us see how least square cross-validation with the leave-one-out method produces an "unbiased" estimate of $\mathrm{IMSE}\left(\widehat{f}\right)$.

Let us define the objective function of least square cross-validation as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
LSCV&=\int[\widehat{f}(x)-f(x)]^2 d x \\
&=\underbrace{\int[\widehat{f}(x)]^2 d x}_{=:\mathcal{I}_{1n}}-2 \underbrace{\int \widehat{f}(x) f(x) d x}_{=:\mathcal{I}_{2n}}+\int f^2(x) d x \\
&=\mathcal{I}_{1n} - 2\mathcal{I}_{2n}+\int f^2(x) d x\\
&={\mathcal{I}}_{1n} - 2\widehat{\mathcal{I}}_{2n}+\int f^2(x) d x + o_{\mathbb{P}}(1),\\
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\widehat{\mathcal{I}}_{2n}$ denotes the estimand of ${\mathcal{I}}_{2n}$.

The leave-one-out method is applied to the computation of $\widehat{\mathcal{I}}_{2n}$. To ease of exposition, let me define two versions of
$\mathcal{I}_{2n}$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{\mathcal{I}_{2n}}^{\text{LOO}} :=& \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \widehat{f}_{-i}\left(X_i\right) =\frac{1}{n^2 h} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1, j \neq i}^n K\left(\frac{X_j-X_i}{h}\right),\\
\widehat{\mathcal{I}_{2n}}^{\text{without LOO}} :=& \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \widehat{f}\left(X_i\right)=\frac{1}{n^{2}h} \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n K\left(\frac{X_j-X_i}{h}\right).
\end{aligned}
$$
Notice that their only difference lies in:
$$
\widehat{\mathcal{I}_{2n}}^{\text{without LOO}} = \widehat{\mathcal{I}_{2n}}^{\text{LOO}} + \frac{1}{n h} K(0).
$$
But as we will see later, **this difference plays a key role in the conclusion that without leave-one-out, the objective function $LSCV$ is biased concerning $\mathrm{IMSE}$ and is minimized at $h=0$, which violates the condition of $n h \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.**

Now, taking the expectation $\mathbb{E}_{X}(\cdot)$ to $LSCV^{\text{LOO}}$ gives:
$$
\mathbb{E}_{X}\left(LSCV^{\text{LOO}}\right) = \mathbb{E}_{X}\left[{\mathcal{I}}_{1 n}\right]-2 \mathbb{E}_{X}\left[\widehat{\mathcal{I}}_{2 n}^{\text{LOO}}\right]+\int f^2(x) d x.
$$
The first term is computed as:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}_{X}\left[{\mathcal{I}}_{1 n}\right]=& \mathbb{E}_{X}\left[\int[\widehat{f}(x)]^2 d x\right] = \int\mathbb{E}_{X}\left[[\widehat{f}(x)]^2\right]  d x\\
 =& \int\mathrm{Var}\widehat{f}(x)  d x + \int\mathbb{E}_{X}^2\left[\widehat{f}(x)\right]  d x \\
=&\int  \frac{f(x)}{n h} \nu_2+o\left(\frac{1}{n h}\right)  + \left(f(x)+\frac{h^2}{2} f^{\prime \prime}(x) \kappa_2 + o\left(h^2\right)\right)^{2} dx \\
=& \frac{\nu_2}{n h}+o\left(\frac{1}{n h}\right) + \int f^{2}(x) dx + \frac{h^4}{4} \int u^2 K(u) d u \int\left[f^{\prime \prime}(x)\right]^2 d x+o\left(h^4\right)\\
& + \int h^{2}f(x)f^{\prime \prime}(x) \kappa_2 dx + 2 \int f(x)o\left(h^2\right) dx ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where the third line can be referred (again) to the [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/439199/expected-value-and-variance-of-kde/588761#588761) and
$$
\nu_2:=\int K^2(u) d u.
$$
The second term is computed as:
$$
\begin{aligned}
2 \mathbb{E}_X\left[\widehat{\mathcal{I}}_{2 n}^{\mathrm{LOO}}\right] =& \mathbb{E}_{X}\left[\frac{1}{n^2 h} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1, j \neq i}^n2 K\left(\frac{X_j-X_i}{h}\right)\right] = \mathbb{E}_{X}\left[\frac{2(n-1)}{n^{2}} \sum_{i=1}^n \widehat{f}_{-i}(X_{i})\right] \\
=& \frac{2(n-1)}{n^{2}} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}_{X_{i}}\left[\mathbb{E}_{X_{-i}}\left[\widehat{f}_{-i}(X_{i})\right]\right] \\
=& \frac{2(n-1)}{n^{2}} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}_{X_{i}}\left[f(X_{i})+\frac{h^2}{2} f^{\prime \prime}(X_{i}) \kappa_2+o\left(h^2\right)\right] \\
=& \frac{2(n-1)}{n} \int\left[f(X_{i})+\frac{h^2}{2} f^{\prime \prime}(X_{i}) \kappa_2+o\left(h^2\right)\right]f(X_{i}) d X_{i}\\
=& \frac{2(n-1)}{n} \int\left[f(x)+\frac{h^2}{2} f^{\prime \prime}(x) \kappa_2+o\left(h^2\right)\right]f(x) d x\\
=& \frac{2(n-1)}{n} \int f^{2}(x) dx +\frac{2(n-1)}{n} \int \frac{h^2}{2} f^{\prime \prime}(x)f(x)  \kappa_2 dx + \frac{2(n-1)}{n} o\left(h^2\right)  \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Inserting the two expressions back $\mathbb{E}_{X}\left[{LSCV}^{\text{LOO}}(h)\right]$ gives:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \mathbb{E}_{X}\left[{LSCV}^{\text{LOO}}(h)\right]\\
=& \frac{\nu_2}{n h}+o\left(\frac{1}{n h}\right) + \int f^{2}(x) dx + \frac{h^4}{4} \int u^2 K(u) d u \int\left[f^{\prime \prime}(x)\right]^2 d x+o\left(h^4\right) \\
&+ \int h^{2}f(x)f^{\prime \prime}(x) \kappa_2 dx + 2 \int f(x)o\left(h^2\right) dx \\
&-\left[\frac{2(n-1)}{n} \int f^{2}(x) dx +\frac{2(n-1)}{n} \int \frac{h^2}{2} f^{\prime \prime}(x)f(x)  \kappa_2 dx + \frac{2(n-1)}{n} o\left(h^2\right)\right]+\int f^2(x) d x\\
=& \frac{\nu_2}{n h}+o\left(\frac{1}{n h}\right) + \frac{h^4}{4} \int u^2 K(u) d u \int\left[f^{\prime \prime}(x)\right]^2 d x+o\left(h^4\right) + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right),
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, we can see that
$$
\mathbb{E}_{X}\left[{LSCV}^{\text{LOO}}(h)\right]\sim \operatorname{IMSE}(\widehat{f}).
$$
And it is quite evident to see that
$$
\mathbb{E}_{X}\left[LSC V^{\text {without } L O O}(h)\right]=\mathbb{E}_{X}\left[LSC V^{L O O}(h)\right]-\frac{2}{n h} K(0).
$$

To this end, one can be informed in the context of KDE that the leave-one-out cross-validation provides a relatively “unbiased estimate of the true generalization performance”.